# VBA Mapping Sharepoint Drive to File Explorer To Loop Through PDFS

Tags: excel, vba, networking, sharepoint, drive

I have a script within an excel that needs to loop through whichever folder its in on the Sharepoint, and attach it to an email.

As I understand I need a directory for this and DIR wont work on Sharepoint, so I am mapping the folder the file is in as the Z network drive to the computer and then looping through from there.

However, if the Z drive already exists because I ran this before, I need to remove it which sometimes throws an error of "This network connection has file open or Requests pending" and I cannot remove it, and have to run the script again and it usually works

Here is my code:

```
'Create Directory to find PDF
On Error GoTo mapped:
networkPath.mapnetworkdrive "Z:", ThisWorkbook.path
mapped:
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:10 AM#
networkPath.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:"
networkPath.mapnetworkdrive "Z:", ThisWorkbook.path
file_name = Dir("Z:\*.PDF")

'Find the PDFs
Do While Len(file_name) > 0
    If Right(file_name, 3) = "pdf" Then
        pdf_name = file_name
        GoTo foundpdf
    Else
    End If
Loop
```

Is there a better way to loop through all PDFs on the sharepoint then mapping the Z drive over and over again or is there a better way to overcome the Z drive already existing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dir will lock the files until Windows release it, so don't use it when you need to modify the network. instead, you can do this

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim file As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
For Each file In fso.getfolder("Z:\").files
    If Split(file, ".")(UBound(Split(file, "."))) = "xlsx" Then
        pdf_name = file_name
        GoTo foundpdf
    End If
Next file
```